# "transmission-cli magnet:?file" downloads the file that I want, how would I do the same thing using "transmission-remote"?

Tags: transmission

I have a script that downloads an iso using transmission-cli, but while searching for information on another transmission command issue, I find this

So I can do this:

```
transmission-cli magnet:?xt=urn:btih:375ae3280cd80a8e9d7212e11dfaf7c45069dd35&dn=archlinux-2023.02.01-x86_64.iso
```

But I can't do:

```
transmission-remote magnet:?xt=urn:btih:375ae3280cd80a8e9d7212e11dfaf7c45069dd35&dn=archlinux-2023.02.01-x86_64.iso
```

Trying to do this:

```
transmission-remote -a magnet:?xt=urn:btih:375ae3280cd80a8e9d7212e11dfaf7c45069dd35&dn=archlinux-2023.02.01-x86_64.iso
```

results in this:

```
transmission-remote:  (http://localhost:9091/transmission/rpc/) Couldn't connect to server
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to turn on transmission-daemon for starters.

```
sudo systemctl enable transmission-daemon
sudo systemctl start transmission-daemon
```